# How to create a batch script to copy newly created folder with the current date

Tags: batch-file

im not good in batch scripting. Hope someone can help me with this.

What my problem is, everyday my program creates a dated folder. I want a automated daily backup scripts that will do the job, I want only the newly created folder with the current date or yesterdays date to copy and rar then send to other directory and the rest of the files and subdirectory remains. Btw, My Program creates a folder name according to current date.

here is the sample

```
source todays date: february 26 20013
C:\MyApp\20130226 <new folder
        \20130225 <old folder
        \20130224 <old folder


destination todays date: february 26 20013
D:\Backup\20130226.rar << newly backup according to current date.
```

Is this possible? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Date stuff in batch files is notoriously finicky and tricky.

There are basically two ways of going about that:

1. Use `%DATE%` and cut it to appropriate pieces, e.g. for me it would look like this:

   ```
   > echo %DATE%
   2013-02-26

   > echo %DATE:~0,4%%DATE:~5,2%%DATE:~8,2%
   20130226
   ```

   This has the problem that it's dependent on the date format in your current locale. As you can see, I am using ISO-8601 (the only sane date format imho) which makes this rather easy.

   It works well enough for one-off scripts that you use in a clearly defined environment and have no actual requirements of robustness. I tend to avoid that, though.
2. Use WMI to get the current date:

   ```
   > wmic os get localdatetime
   LocalDateTime
   20130226113553.324000+060
   ```

   You can store that output in a variable with `for /f`:

   ```
   for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
   ```

   Since that format is fixed you can safely use substrings to access the individual parts:

   ```
   echo %MyDate:~0,8%
   ```

I'll leave the actual file copying as an exercise to you.